# NSCollectionView memory leaks

Tags: appkit, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I have an `NSCollectionView` specified as both my DataSource and my Delegate.

I have two issues:

1. Rather than doing the `registerClass` method, attempting to instead use the 3 lines of commented code with the (non-nil) protoNib means of registering with an `NSCollectionView` causes `theItem` to always be nil.
2. Using the class registry option, all works mostly fine.  But if I remove the `willDisplayItem` and `didEndDisplayingItem` stubs, the system eats up gobs of memory on its first call to `itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath` (with thousands of internal calls to these two stubs) and eventually crashes. Instruments shows *thousands* of 4k `@autoreleasepool content items` being created by `AppKit`.

Any idea why this might be happening?

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [self registerClass:[MECollectionViewItem class] forItemWithIdentifier:@"EntityItem"];
//  NSString *nibName = NSStringFromClass([MECollectionViewItem class]);
//  NSNib *protoNib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:nibName bundle:nil];
//  [self registerNib:protoNib forItemWithIdentifier:@"EntityItem"];
    
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self setDelegate:weakSelf];
    [self setDataSource:weakSelf];
    ...
}

- (MECollectionViewItem *)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView
     itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
        MECollectionViewItem *theItem = [self makeItemWithIdentifier:@"EntityItem"
                                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return theItem;
}

-(void)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView
      willDisplayItem:(NSCollectionViewItem *)item
forRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}

-(void)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView
 didEndDisplayingItem:(nonnull NSCollectionViewItem *)item
forRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

Comment: I’m not losing my mind.  https://twitter.com/bitemybyte/status/1147135248913829888

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSCollectionView memory leak in High Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916659/nscollectionview-memory-leak-in-high-sierra)

Comment: Are issue 1 and 2 related? Please ask a question for each issue.

Comment: Issue 2:  to clarify, I have 48 items to create.  Without the the stubs, only one call to makeItemWithIdentifier happens for the first item, then the app beachballs with memory eventually exhausted.

Comment: Ask issue 1 in a new question please.

Answer (score 0):

The Appkit classes are not designed to be their own delegate. `NSCollectionView` implements several `NSCollectionViewDelegate` methods and calls the delegate. I don't know why it's implemented like this and it doesn't feel right but it is what it is. If the collection view is its own delegate and a delegate method isn't implemented in the subclass then the call causes an infinite loop. Solution: don't set `delegate` to `self`.